# Erro code 201 in pascal

Tags: freepascal

I am making a program in pascal in which I am asked to read from a file then put the names in alphabetical order. This is the code i have so far.

```
for counter := 1 to 6 do
    begin 
        readln(infile, name[counter]);
            if names[counter] > names[counter+1] then
                high:=names[counter];
            if  names[counter] < names[counter-1] then
                low:=names[counter];
    end;

    for counter:= 1 to 6 do
        begin
            writeln(names[counter]);
        end;
close(infile);
readln()
end.
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You are reading into `name[]` but all tests are done on `names[]`.

Comment: My question is, I am getting error code 201 why is that? Should I read from names[] then do the test in another variable?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is a range-check error. I guess you have something like `name,names:array[1..6] of string;` and you are accessing indexes 0 throgh 7. RTFM: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html